# NameError: name 'sent_df' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

how to solve this?
can someone help me to solve this please, im beginner in here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wv51.png)
help me to solve this problem, i dont know how to solve this and i cant understand what people post about name error and how to solve it.
please help me and teach me. so i can understand about that problem, thank you.

%%time
sentiment_analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for indx, row in sent_df.T.iteritems():
try:
sentence_i = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', sent_df.loc[indx, 'Tweet'])
sentence_sentiment = sentiment_analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence_i)
sent_df.at[indx, 'sentiment_score'] = sentence_sentiment['compound']
sent_df.at[indx, 'Negative'] = sentence_sentiment['neg']
sent_df.at[indx, 'Neutral'] = sentence_sentiment['neu']
sent_df.at[indx, 'Positive'] = sentence_sentiment['pos']
except TypeError:
print (sent_df.loc[indexx, 'Tweet'])
print (indx)
break